# Load large data from MySQL from R

Tags: mysql, r

I have a large table in MySQL (about 3million rows with 15 columns) and I'm trying to use some of the data from the table in an R shiny app.

I've been able to get the connection and write a query in R:

```
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
cn <- dbConnect(drv      = RMySQL::MySQL(), 
                username = "user", 
                password = "my_password",
                host     = "host", 
                port     = 3306
                )


query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.locations"
```

However, when I run `dbGetQuery(cn, query)` it takes really long (I ended up closing my RStudio program after it turned unresponsive.

I also tried

```
res <- DBI::dbSendQuery (cn, query)
repeat {
  df <- DBI::dbFetch (res, n = 1000)
  if (nrow (df) == 0) { break }
}
dbClearResult(dbListResults(cn)[[1]])
```

since this is similar to reading the data in by chunks, but my resulting `df` has 0 rows for some reason.

Any suggestions on how to get my table in R? Should I even try to read that table into R? From what I understand, R doesn't handle large data very well.

Comment: This could be due to the database (indexing), network environment (latency, bandwidth), an inefficient query, or a problem/inefficiency with `dbGetQuery`. I don't use MySQL so I cannot comment to that side of things, but I routinely query millions of rows without difficulty (though it is admittedly not instantaneous).

Comment: For really large queries, I tend to use `bcp` (I'm using sql server), as it is for the most part as far as will be possible. I don't know if MySQL has similar functionality.

Comment: Finally, R "can" handle larger data just fine, but it has some behaviors that make it somewhat inefficient for that. Namely, most operations do not occur *in-place*, meaning that the data is easily copied. For this task, I've been using `data.table` and its referential semantics for a bit now (learning curve!) and am very pleased with the performance and ability to deal with larger datasets. There are still many operations where a copy cannot be avoided, but that package does it far less.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I guess the first time I ran `dbGetQuery` it didn't work, but it works fine now. Strangely enough I had to click around to get the df to show up in the environment, but it's there. I've been considering using `data.table` too after having read a bit about it, but I guess I'll see how the default performance goes

Comment: Dealing with frames that large, I encourage it, but admit that its learning curve is not flat. To learn it, I "stalked" a lot of [tag:data.table] questions and answers, trying to solve the simpler questions myself. I wouldn't say I'm a pro at it, but working with a lot of many smaller questions helped me learn it for my larger (~50M row) projects. (I admit that I prefer to use `data.table`+`magrittr`, in a tidyverse-analog kind of way. It affords `data.table`'s speed and memory-efficiency with what may be more readable code (for me).)